# Apache errors when retrieving taxonomies

Tags: themes

I'm regularly seeing Apache errors when my category-single-page.php is pulling in the categories related to a post:

```
PHP Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, bool given in /wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/category-single-page.php on line 4
```

This is the first few lines from the php file (lines numbered for reference only NOT in the actual file)

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
    $thiscategory = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_name );
    $thiscategory = array_values( $thiscategory );  // This is line 4
    $section = get_post_type( $post->ID );
    $thispost = $post->ID;
?>
```

The php file doesn't seem to generate an error all of the time it is called - so I think my code is OK (I could be wrong!) so any thoughts of what could be causing Apache to log the error on occasion, or is it my code at fault?

Comment: Just before line 4 can you add `var_dump( $thiscategory );` and check if it is indeed an array?

Answer (score 0):

It's a PHP error, not an Apache error.

What's happening is that [`get_the_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) returns an array of terms, or `false` if there are no terms or the post doesn't exist.

You can fix this like this:

```
$thiscategory = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_name );
if ( is_array( $thiscategory ) ) {
    // Only runs if $thiscategory is an array.
    $thiscategory = array_values( $thiscategory );  // This is line 4
}
$section = get_post_type( $post->ID );
$thispost = $post->ID;
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought it was something like this causing it - but got my head so messed up trying to find where the issue was never thought to trap it! Apologies for the error in my description - of course it's Apache showing a PHP error. Thanks again, Stuart

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please mark it **Accepted**, which will help others having similar problems.